# Is a primitive type an object?

Tags: java, types

The start of the [Reflection tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/class/index.html) @ the Java Tutorials states:

> Every object is either a reference or primitive type.

Apart from the types used to box primitive types, when and how is a primitive type an object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It says `object`, not `Object`. `int`, for example, is a primitive type and an `object`(interpret as the general termn), but not an `Object`.

Comment: I see the distinction - they're speaking in generalities. Poor choice of words IMO.

Comment: Agreed. Easy to get confused if you don't know what they want to say, which, if you did, you probably wouldn't be reading that article.

Comment: As I wrote in my answer the term object has different meanings in different context even without taking the Object class into account.

Answer (score 1):

The classification is exclusive, that means that if a variable is a primitive type, it is not a reference to an `Object` (an entity that has attributes and methods).

In this case, the author is using the term *object* (in lowercase) as a synonym of a *thing* (variable, parameter, constant, attribute, whatever) that holds a value.

Comment: "Every object is ... or a primitive type". But given that the author doesn't even bother with the distinction between types and values, I'd be careful with looking for exact words anyway.

Comment: Hmmm.. I think my brain just omitted the beginning of the sentence xD

Answer (score 1):

According to the Java Language Specification:

> An *object* is a *class instance* or an array.

Here's the [relevant paragraph](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/typesValues.html#4.3.1).

However there is a source for misunderstandings in the fact that there are contexts where the term *object* is used to mean roughly any piece of memory that can be explicitly referenced in a program. With this definition attributes and variables of primitive types are indeed objects.

Answer (score 1):

> ・The types of the Java programming language are divided into two
>   categories: primitive types and reference types.
>
> ・The primitive types are the boolean type and the numeric types.
>
> ・The reference types are class types, interface types, and array
>   types. There is also a special null type.
>
> ・An object is a dynamically created instance of a class type or a
>   dynamically created array.

So,  a primitive type can't be an object. But if you say everything in the world is object, then it is.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is an object. An object is a type of something with definitions on how you can create it (contructor). A primitive type doesn't have this, it's value gets stored directly onto memory.

Answer (score 0):

I would assume that the same would apply for classes.

class and java.lang.Class

Answer (score 0):

In Java a primitive type cannot be an Object.

The primitive types are not accessed with references, but direct. If you pass them to a method, they are copied. If you pass an Object, only the reference to it is copied. Primitives don't have any overhead in memory, like Objects, they need as much bytes as specified in their definition (for example int needs 4). Using an Integer Object, it uses more than the 4 Integer bytes.